# mysql function, strip non-alphanumeric characters & leading and/or trailing "the"

Tags: mysql, string, user-defined-functions, string-comparison

Would anyone be so kind as to help with a mysql custom function that would strip a text string of any non-alphanumeric characters (including spaces), remove "the" from the beginning and/or end, and make the string all uppercase?

I've tried to piece together various functions from around the web with no luck. Any hep would be much appreciated.

As per @Barmar 's request I've placed more info on what I've tried below. Although I've tried various things this is the closest I've gotten (from what I can tell.) I think this should get me the string stripped of non-alphanumeric but not sure it will help with spaces and removing the "the" from the beginning and end.

This is the error I'm getting:

> error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@Temp VarChar(1000))

This is the code:

```
Create Function `coverdb`.`stripdown`(@Temp VarChar(1000))
RETURNS VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50) = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Comment: @barmar I've edited above per your request. Thanks for your help.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have the `PatIndex()` and `Stuff()` functions. It looks like you're trying to use a solution intended for a different DBMS.

Comment: I think the error is because you shouldn't use variables beginning with `@` as function parameters. Just use `Temp`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. That unfortunately doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you might want to use REPLACE() and UPPER()

you can mix them

```
SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(Field),'THE ','')
```

or add more complex cases to remove from start or end

```
SELECT UPPER(CASE WHEN Field LIKE 'the %' THEN SUBSTR(Field,5) ELSE Field END) AS UpperredField
```

Try various combinations, it might work for you.